# How to map /usr/bin/pdftotext to another path?

Tags: pdf, centos-7

I recently installed the poppler-utils:

```
sudo yum -y install poppler-utils
```

I did this so I can get pdftotext but when I run pdftotext, I get this:

```
pdftotext version 0.26.5
Copyright 2005-2014 The Poppler Developers - http://poppler.freedesktop.org
```

This is the incorrect pdftotext I want. I realised the correct one is the one I have running locally:

```
pdftotext version 4.03 [www.xpdfreader.com]
Copyright 1996-2021 Glyph & Cog, LLC
```

I managed to install pdftotext from xpdfreader.com and I extracted it to /var/tmp/xpdf-tools-linux-4.03. If I got to this folder and run it, it works and I can see it is executing version 4.03.  The problem is, if I run it from any other folder, it executes the pdftotext located at:

```
/usr/bin/pdftotext
```

How do I replace /usr/bin/pdftotext with the pdftotext I extracted to /var/tmp? Is it as simple as doing this:

```
cp /var/tmp/xpdf-tools-linux-4.03/bin64/pdftotext /usr/bin/pdftotext
```

Or am I missing any other important steps?

Comment: You should not overwrite package-managed files with random downloaded binaries. Consider using `/usr/local/bin`  or even `/opt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the reply from Daniel, you can uninstall `poppler-utils` and move your files to `/usr/local/bin/` by running this:

`mv /var/tmp/xpdf-tools-linux-4.03/bin64/* /usr/local/bin/`

You should then be able to execute `pdftotext` within any directory and run version 4.03 as expected.